# How to solve a function and get three unknown variables?

Tags: python, scipy, sympy

I am trying to find `x_my`, `y_my` and `z_my` from the function `f` below. I have three values for `f` as well as three values for each corresponding `curr_location`. This means I have three equations and three unknown meaning it can be solved. But I have no idea how to do this with python.

```
sigma_x=3
sigma_y=3
sigma_z=3

curr_location_x1=3
curr_location_y1=3
curr_location_z1=3

curr_location_x2=4
curr_location_y2=4
curr_location_z2=4

curr_location_x3=6
curr_location_y3=6
curr_location_z3=6

f_1=0.4
f_2=0.3
f_3=0.24

f = math.exp(-((((curr_location_x - x_my) * (curr_location_x - x_my)) / (2*sigma_x * sigma_x)) + (((curr_location_y - y_my) *(curr_location_y - y_my)) / (2 * sigma_y * sigma_y)) + (((curr_location_z - z_my) *(curr_location_z - z_my)) / (2 * sigma_z * sigma_z))))
```

Comment: What have you read about the problem? In what way was the material you read inadequate?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `curve_fit` ([docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html)). Note how you put input and outputs in vectors:

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import numpy as np

sigma_x=3
sigma_y=3
sigma_z=3

def f(curr_location, x_my, y_my, z_my):
    curr_location_x, curr_location_y, curr_location_z = curr_location
    return np.exp(-((((curr_location_x - x_my) * (curr_location_x - x_my))
                     / (2*sigma_x * sigma_x)) + (((curr_location_y - y_my)
                     *(curr_location_y - y_my)) / (2 * sigma_y * sigma_y)) +
    (((curr_location_z - z_my) *(curr_location_z - z_my)) /
 (2 * sigma_z * sigma_z))))

curr_location_values = [[3,3,3,], [4,4,4], [6,6,6]]
output_values = [0.4, 0.3, 0.24]
popt, pcov = curve_fit(f, curr_location_values, output_values)
popt
>> array([2.99570375, 2.38445522, 1.7246244 ])
```